# useLocation hook keeps states even on hard refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

While working on a project I noticed a weird behavior of the `useLocation` hook that I can`t find an explanation to.

I have a button that when clicked it will redirect you to an `EditOrder` page and will pass a state with it:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleClick = (data) => {
    navigate("edit-order", {state: {order: data}})
};
```

In the `EditOrder` page I check with a `UseEffect` hook if a `state` was provided and if not the user will be redirected to a different page:

```
const { state } = useLocation();

const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
    if (!state) {
        navigate("some-page");
    }
}, []);
```

The weird part is when I refresh the page I can still access it, and if I `console.log(state.order)` the data is still there, even when I reload with `ctrl + shift + r` the state stays the same, and this also happens with the `empty cache and hard reload option`  (tried in both chrome and edge).

But when I copy the URL and past it in a new tab I immediately get redirected to "some-page"
and `console.log(state)` will show `null`.

I checked both the cookies and local storage and I can't find the state data there.

Can someone explain why is this happening and how the state data is being saved?

Edit:

Here is a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBGyefJpIhY) that shows this behavior.

The code on the video can be found in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/location-state-stay-on-hard-refresh-q6bjxn?file=/src/App.js), when you run the code on sandbox it runs as it should, on refresh all the states reset, but when running locally this problem occurs (on 2 different computers).

[A git repo about location.state](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#locationstate)

Comment: Peculiar behavior... think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I created a send-box but I can't reproduce this issue, however, when I copy this sandbox to my machine and run it locally the issue occurs https://codesandbox.io/s/location-state-stay-on-hard-refresh-q6bjxn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue and see the same behavior in the CSB as well as when the code is running in a new window. After navigating to `"/page2"` I see the object logged, and upon reloading the page the object is null and UI redirects back to `"/"`.  The same occurs when navigating manually to `"/page2"`. This is what I'd expect the behavior to be.

Comment: Even when you run it on your local computer? I will go run the code on my second computer and will update if it still happens.

Comment: So I just downloaded the code from the sandbox on my second computer and it still happens both in chrome and edge... I will update the question with all this new information.

Comment: Just so we're on the same page about what you mean by "run it on local computer" can you clarify exactly what this means? The code in the CSB is running locally on my machine in the browser.

Comment: I meant that I downloaded the code to my computer and ran it with `npm start`

Comment: Ok, so I've also downloaded the sandbox code and run it locally. Curiously I'm able to repro the "issue" of state persistence upon page reloads. I thought maybe it was RRDv6 so tried v5 and again reproed. I then tried Safari (vs Chrome) and again reproed. Search the repo for issues and found this [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/history/issues/331#issuecomment-233002819) and was surprised to find state is supposed to persist reloads. I suspect the code running in the sandbox is running differently since it's in an iframe.

Comment: if you want to refresh the page on redirect, use `window.location.href="/"` the whole meaning behind useNavigate() is to keep the state.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React's useLocation [is based](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#location) on the [history library](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#location), which uses the `BrowserHistory` in web apps.

[Some browsers](https://github.com/remix-run/history/issues/557), like Chrome, persist `BrowserHistory` state between sessions, while others (like Firefox) do not.

This is likely why you're seeing this behavior locally but not in a Sandbox. It appears that CodeSandbox's browser clears history state on refresh. It's also why, if you copy the URL into another tab, the redirect works. `BrowserHistory` is local to a single tab.

In short, this is intended behavior. Either you need to clear the history state manually or store your application state elsewhere (`useContext` could be a good choice if you want to persist across pages but *not* across a refresh).